# Undefined symbol error

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm working on a base project by someone else and I'm kind of new to the Linux system.

I know how to use sqlite3 in Windows' Visual Studio, however in Linux it's not working.

I've come to the thought that it might be because of the make file, here it is:

```
LIBPS4  :=  $(PS4SDK)/libPS4

TEXT    :=  0x926200000
DATA    :=  0x926300000

CC  :=  gcc
AS  :=  gcc
OBJCOPY :=  objcopy
ODIR    :=  build
SDIR    :=  source
IDIRS   :=  -I$(LIBPS4)/include -I. -Iinclude
LDIRS   :=  -L$(LIBPS4) -L. -Llib
CFLAGS  :=  $(IDIRS) -O2 -std=gnu11 -fno-builtin -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wall -masm=intel -march=btver2 -mtune=btver2 -m64 -mabi=sysv -mcmodel=large
SFLAGS  :=  -nostartfiles -nostdlib -masm=intel -march=btver2 -mtune=btver2 -m64 -mabi=sysv -mcmodel=large
LFLAGS  :=  $(LDIRS) -Xlinker -T $(LIBPS4)/linker.x -Wl,--build-id=none -Ttext=$(TEXT) -Tdata=$(DATA)
CFILES  :=  $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.c)
SFILES  :=  $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.s)
OBJS    :=  $(patsubst $(SDIR)/%.c, $(ODIR)/%.o, $(CFILES)) $(patsubst $(SDIR)/%.s, $(ODIR)/%.o, $(SFILES))

LIBS    :=  -lPS4 -lpthread

TARGET = $(shell basename $(CURDIR)).bin

$(TARGET): $(ODIR) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LIBPS4)/crt0.s $(ODIR)/*.o -o temp.t $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary temp.t $(TARGET)
    rm -f temp.t

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $&lt; $(CFLAGS)

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.s
    $(AS) -c -o $@ $&lt; $(SFLAGS)

$(ODIR):
    @mkdir $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(ODIR)/*.o
```

I'm getting an error of:

```
/usr/bin/ld: build/shell.o: undefined reference to symbol 'fflush@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: I imaging that's because you are passing `CFLAGS` to the link phase, and it includes `-nostdlib` (and your `LIBS` doesn't contain anything to replace the standard libraries that you are telling the linker to skip)

Comment: @steeldriver "Compilation finished at Thu Mar 29 17:05:53", I did as u said and succeed in building it, however, it's a payload for the ps4 and I'm afraid to check if it works lol. is there any risk in using stdlib? why did the creator put that cflag in the first place anyway?

Comment: Sorry - don't know

Comment: @steeldriver tried on the ps4, didn't work (out of memory issue), i didn't change the sqlite code though, so i suspect that stdlib isn't working normally and the creator has changed the files. it can't even open the file using sqlite3_open, i'd give up on it for now, thank u for the great suggestion, it made me realize what the creator has done, and get to the conclusion that it'd take alot of time to make it work (recreating all the missing parts basically). thank you for your time, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I can't be more help - good luck anyway